# BigQuery modulo operator (%) does not work in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

When I used modulo operator (%) in WHERE clause on BigQuery,

```
SELECT * from `our-project.data_set1.table1` WHERE the_id % 10 = 0 LIMIT 1000
```

it was rejected with the error message like as;

> Error: Syntax error; Illegal input character "%" at [1:50]

I made the turn-around like,

```
SELECT * from `our-project.data_set1.table1` 
WHERE CAST((the_id / 10) AS INT64) * 10 = the_id LIMIT 1000
```

However, it seems to be wasteful.

How can I use modulo operation in BigQuery's WHERE clause?

*(In this example, I wrote in Standard SQL Dialect)*

Comment: You sure there is no mod function instead

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#mathematical-functions

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try `mod(id, 10) = 0` instead in the where clause